# Update links in Excel files

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to modify some Excel files that link to other Excel files.

The files that are linked to are in sub-directories. I am going to move all the files to a root directory and then run a script to change the links.

I am able to find the links within each file but I am unable to modify them (see below)

Any ideas?

Thanks

P

```sh
#get all the excel files in the directory

Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Filter *.xl* |

Foreach-Object {

write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow $_.FullName



$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)



foreach ($link in $workbook.LinkSources(1))

{

write-host $link.Address

#this gives me .... C:\temp\files\childfile1.xlsx etc

# $link.Address seems to be read only?

#$link.Address = $newLink

#this doesn't seem to work either ...

#$workbook. .ChangeLink($link,$newlink,1)

}





#$workbook.Save()

$workbook.Close()
```

Comment: write-host $Tab -ForegroundColor White $link.Address

                    #Y:\Deirdre\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy2\Phased Budget 2020.xlsx
                    $link.Address = "C:\\temp\Finance\child.xlsx"

                    write-host $Tab -ForegroundColor White $link.Address The property 'Address' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are modifying XLSX files, you can update the link without using Excel.  Ultimately these are a zip archive with a different extension.  If you create a copy of the file to have a ZIP extension, you can use Expand-Archive to access the various files and update those accordingly, then Compress-Archive to generate a new Excel file.

In the archive, look for /workbook.xml, which will identify sheets by name.  /rels/workbook.xlm.rels can be used to translate from sheetId to the worksheet (Target), a file in /worksheets (e.g. "worksheets/sheets3.xml") and you can infer the relationship file, which will be in /workseets/_rels (e.g. /worksheets/_rels/sheet3.xml).

Using the worksheet you can find the associated hyperlink based upon cell reference, using  the ref attribute, which gives you the r:id attribute. Us can us this value to lookup up the appropriate Relationship by Id.  You would then need to update the Target appropriately.

Of course, if you know your original link, and it is unique (or you are altering them all the same way), you could do a search and replace across the .rels files.

Once you've saved you change, you just need to create the new file, which you can do using Compress-Archive.  You'll need to do this to a file with a .Zip extension, then rename.

---

Here is an example based upon a XSLX with a link to Yahoo on the first sheet *(note: the first 3 sheets normally have the XML and sheet names match, until altered. Don't count on that for production)*

```
copy-item c:\temp\links.xlsx c:\temp\links.zip 
expand-archive c:\temp\links.zip c:\temp\links_zip
$content = get-content c:\temp\links_zip\xl\worksheets\_rels\sheet1.xml.rels -raw # allow file to close
$content |  %{ $_ -replace 'http://www.yahoo.com','http://www.google.com'} | set-content c:\temp\links_zip\xl\worksheets\_rels\sheet1.xml.rels
compress-archive c:\temp\links_zip\* c:\temp\links_alt.zip 
remove-item c:\temp\links_zip -Recurse
rename-item c:\temp\links_alt.zip c:\temp\links_alt.xlsx
c:\temp\links_alt.xlsx
```

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks for your answer. <br>I used powershell to copy the file to a zip, modify the links and extract the zip back to excel but I seem to be doing something wrong.<br>C:\temp\Finance\parentfile1\parentfile1 zip\xl\worksheets\_rels contains the links so I modify them there.

Comment: @PeteWhelan Check the before and after XML when you update.  Also check that you are zipping up the files in the folder you extracted, not the extracted folder itself (otherwise you are adding an additional level of folders).

Comment: Thanks Graham I've tried this a few times. Modifying the paths within the xml files that are in xl\externalLinks\_rels but when I open the Excel file after making those changes it is blank.I use PowerShell to do the copying and zip stuff. The Excel file that I create at the end does seem to have a size greater than 0KB

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> copy-item "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy2\Mgt Accts APR 20.xlsx" -Destination "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy2\Mgt Accts APR 20.zip"

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Expand-Archive "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy2\Mgt Accts APR 20.zip" -DestinationPath "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy2\Mgt Accts APR 20 zipped"

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Compress-Archive -Path "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy2\Mgt Accts APR 20 zipped" -DestinationPath "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy2\Mgt Accts APR 20 (fixed)" 

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Copy-Item "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy2\Mgt Accts APR 20 (fixed).zip" -Destination "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy2\Mgt Accts APR 20 (fixed).xlsx"

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: I've added an example round trip in my answer.  For your code, in compress-archive add a '\*'  to the end of your path value, otherwise it will include the folder as well, which throws off the hierarchy: Compress-Archive -Path "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy2\Mgt Accts APR 20 zipped\*"...

Comment: Thanks @Graham process still seems to corrupt the file, even if I make no changes to the rels files.

Comment: #1
Copy-item "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy3\Mgt Accts APR 20.xlsx" -Destination "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy3\Mgt Accts APR 20.zip"

#2
Expand-Archive "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy3\Mgt Accts APR 20.zip" -DestinationPath "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy3\Mgt Accts APR 20 unzipped"

Comment: #3
Compress-Archive -Path "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy3\Mgt Accts APR 20 unzipped*" -DestinationPath "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy3\Mgt Accts APR 20 (fixed).zip" 

#4
Copy-Item "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy3\Mgt Accts APR 20 (fixed).zip" -Destination "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy3\Mgt Accts APR 20 (fixed).xlsx"

Comment: Thanks @Graham I got it from your edited answer above! Thank you so much for your help on this!